# What does these line of codes mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out someone else's codes. It is written by Javascript. I am more familiar with Jquery.

I know it's a function but not sure that these parameters for (imaglist,sucess, hobject). Thanks for the help.

```
var mystuff = new Object();

var all_done = function (imagelist,success,hobject){
  //alert(success);


mystuff = imagelist.list;

}
```

Comment: We don't know what the parameters are used for either, since we did not write the code. Have a look how the function is called and try to figure it out.

Comment: This may be just a fraction of the whole code, so it's quite hard to figure out what the code should do.

Comment: Since all we basically have to go on is the name of the variable (thanks to Javascript, we don't even know type), there's really nothing we can do to help. Name can be a rough guideline, but it's up to you to find where this function is called, and figure it out from there.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. I strongly suggest learning more plain JavaScript. It will greatly improve your understanding of jQuery as well. Objects and functions aren't really rare to use in combination with jQuery

Comment: "It is written by Javascript. I am more familiar with Jquery." You are aware that even jQuery is just a framework written in and utilizing JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it's just a function, with imagelist, success, and hobject as parameters. So you'd call it like :

```
all_done(anImagelist, somethingRepresentingSuccess, myHobject)
```

But in this case, it looks like all_done is a **callback function**, which is called when something (not shown here) finishes. imagelist, success, and hobject are callback variables, which are results of whatever function the callback is assigned to.

Lets say we have an ajax call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: something,
   success: all_done
});
```

now when the ajax call is completed, the results of it, assuming there are three, will be passed to all_done. Really I'm not even sure if this is possible with an ajax call, but the idea is what's important. So, when the ajax call is complete, `mystuff` will be set to imagelist.list;

Comment: @FelixKling just an assumption, given that it is called "all_done" and there is a commented out `alert("success")`, lol. I was assuming the OP wanted to know what it *does*, not what it *is*. I'll edit and clarify, though

Comment: yes this is a ajax callback function.

Comment: @Flying: You should include relevant information in your question, from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function accepting three parameters (`imagelist`, `success`, and `hobject`).
You can call it with `all_done(some_list, some_state, some_object);`

It's *basically* the same as writing the function like this:

```
function all_done(imagelist, success, hobject) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That is not correct. Function declarations are not automatically global, they a local as well. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EFQwA/

Comment: @FelixKling: not with JS, afaik.

Comment: But I know ;) You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @FelixKling: ha. Must have confused JS with some other language. TODO: learn something new today [✔]

Comment: :) It's always good to learn something new :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You have your `mystuff` `Object` to which you can attach any properties you want. Then you have `all_done` which stores a function that receives `imagelist,success,hobject` and when that function it's triggered whatever you sent to it as `imagelist` wich is also an object that must contain the attribute `list` will be attached to the `mystuff` `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it stores a function into a variable named all_done. If the all_done function was called right after the code you posted, then mystuff becomes imagelist.list:

```
    var imagelist = {list:"myList"};
    var mystuff = new Object();
    var all_done = function (imagelist,success,hobject){
    //alert(success);
    mystuff = imagelist.list;
    }
    all_done(imagelist,true,null);
    alert(mystuff==imagelist.list);//should alert true
    alert(mystuff);//should alert myList
```